# Addition and substraction of 2 vectors using queue and stack in C++

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I have a problem with my C++ code. I need to add and substract 2 math vectors component by component using some header files but I can also implement some other functions. The thing is that my program doesn't have any errors but it's not executing... For example, if I have vector A(3,5) and B(1,7) the results should be: A+B=(4,12) and A-B=(2, -2). This is my main .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "queque.h"
#include "stack_base.h"
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class App {
    public:
        Stack<T> stack;
        T minEle;
        App(Stack<T> stack) {
            this->stack = stack;
        }
        T sum(){
            Stack<T> tempStack = stack;
            T sum=1;
            for(int i=0;i<stack.getTopLevel();i++){

            sum+=tempStack.peek();
            tempStack.pop();
        }
            return sum;
        }
        T substract(){
            Stack<T> tempStack = stack;
            T sum=1;
            for(int i=0;i<stack.getTopLevel();i++){

            sum-=tempStack.peek();
            tempStack.pop();
        }
            return sum;
        }
};

int main(){
  Stack<int> myStack;
    App<int> a(myStack);
    int values[7] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 6};
    int values1[7] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 6};
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    myStack.push(values[i]);
    myStack.push(values1[i]);
    cout<<a.sum();
  return 0;
}
```

Also, here you  can find the queque.h file: https://pastebin.com/yg0CdCnd and the stack_base: https://pastebin.com/P6rzQJC1 Thanks, any help would be useful!

Comment: I don't know if it is the only problem here but, the line `myStack.push(values1[i]);` is not inside the for block.

Comment: Nope, this is not the problem, i also added another for loop and the same @EralpŞahin

Comment: int main should be int main () .even if it doesnt fix it, by convention. That may have just introduced a block and not defined main

Comment: @robi10101298 1) Do not post links that will go stale at some point, thus making this question worthless.  Post the code here.  2) Please define what you mean by "it's not executing" or "it doesn't work".  3) *The thing is that my program doesn't have any errors* -- If your program has no errors, why is there an issue?  If you mean no *syntax* errors, then all that means is that your program is syntactically correct -- it has no bearing on whether the program is logically correct.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's not executing means that if I click on run nothing happens, the terminal it's stucked on a infinite loop that it says that the program it's ,,running" , even if on the screen it's not showing anything

Comment: @robi10101298 But your code contains obvious syntax errors, such as `main()` not being defined (the linker shouldn't even have allowed the program to be created), in addition to accessing the loop index `i` out of the loop body, thus outside `i`'s scope.  What compiler are you using?  Or is this hastily typed-in code, and this isn't your real program?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Codeblocks with GNU GCC Compiler... The program was executed without that (), I've added it and still doesn't show me anything, only a black screen with an infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because when you create your `App` object here

```
App<int> a(myStack);
```

You are creating a new Stack for the object `a` by copying your `myStack`. Pushing data to the variable `myStack` won't change the `Stack<T>` variable inside your object `a`.

To have the expected result, you need to change your class `App` so that it should have a pointer to a `Stack<T>` data member such as:

```
Stack<T> * stack;
```

After that, update your constructor to correspond your data member:

```
App(Stack<T> &stack) {
    this->stack = &stack;
}
T substract(){
    Stack<T> tempStack = *stack;
    T sum=1;
    for(int i=0; i<=stack->getTopLevel(); i++) {
        sum-=tempStack.peek();
        tempStack.pop();
    }
    return sum;
}
T sum(){
    Stack<T> tempStack = *stack;
    T sum=1;
    for(int i=0; i<=stack->getTopLevel(); i++) {
        sum+=tempStack.peek();
        tempStack.pop();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

That should do it. Also you are defining a `NMAX 10` in your `stack_base.h` file and `NMAX 5` in `queque.h` file. That limits the number of the elements in your stack. As far as your code implies `queque.h` is unnecessary. Remove the `#include "queque.h"` line and changing the line you are defining `NMAX` to something like `#define NMAX 20` in the `stack_base.h` file. So that `myStack` could contain 20 elements. Your main function should look like this at the end:

```
int main(){
    Stack<int> myStack;
    App<int> a(myStack);
    int values[7] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 6};
    int values1[7] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 6};
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        myStack.push(values[i]);
        myStack.push(values1[i]);
    }
    cout<<a.sum()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

59 should be displayed which is 1 more than the summation of your elements since you initialized your `sum` variable to 1.

Comment: _"Your loop condition in the sum() method was also false, since you were updating topLevel variable in your pop() method"_ - nope. I thought that at first as well, but that condition refers to `stack` and the `pop` operates on `tempStack`. Confusing code though. Much clearer to just `pop` off the tempStack as I did in my answer.

Comment: @GrahamS oh yeah, you are right.  I changed the `sum()` method, so because of the changes `tempStack` is a pointer and popping from it would affect the `stack->getTopLevel()`

Comment: If you make `tempStack` a pointer instead of a copy then it serves no purpose. Calling `sum()` would then have the nasty side effect of emptying the stack!

Comment: @GrahamS Also right, I was focused on making the data member a pointer, and missed this.

Comment: @EralpŞahin it finally worked, thanks, now I should add vectors component by component

Comment: @robi10101298 if that solves your problem, accepting the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @EralpŞahin yep, partially solved but I'll accept it and try to solve the problems by myself

Answer (score 2):

You need to add parantheses to your main function otherwise it won't run.

```
int main()
{
  Stack<int> myStack;
  App<int> a(myStack);
  int values[7] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 6};
  int values1[7] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 6};
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
  myStack.push(values[i]);
  myStack.push(values1[i]);
  cout<<a.sum();
  return 0;
}
```

I have not checked if your code is correct, but that's the reason why it will not execute.

Comment: Also is that `for` loop correct? I think you probably wanted _both_ of the `push` calls in the body of the loop.

Comment: Did this, thanks for help, but still doesn't work :( I forgot about this parantheses

Comment: @GrahamS I don't think it's correct..Yes, I wanted both, I added another for but this doesn't seems to work

Comment: You also want to change your output line to be: `cout << a.sum() << endl;` otherwise the output may not get flushed.

Comment: @robi10101298 What is `a.sum()`?  Why aren't you inspecting that function?  And how are you so sure that any of those functions actually do the job correctly?  If you erased all of that code and just had `std::cout << "Hello World";` -- do you see that?  If so, then you need to do further debugging of your code, especially those classes you're just assuming "work":.

Comment: I don't see anything, still stucked on this, I don't know if it's a Codeblocks problem..

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `sum()` and `subtract()` is flawed. You shouldn't refer to `getTopLevel` at all. It is defined in the linked header file as being the index of the top item of the stack in the internal array. This is an implementation detail of `Stack` and shouldn't really be part of the public interface.

Instead I suggest you use `Stack` as it is intended - by *pushing* elements onto it and then *popping* off the top element as required.

e.g.

```
    T sum()
    {
        Stack<T> tempStack = stack;
        T sum = 0;

        while (!tempStack.isEmpty())
        {
            sum += tempStack.pop();
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answear, I also tried something like this but it seems that it doesn't work :(